# Using UITableView with storyboard but separate datasource

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, datasource

**EDIT** Answer below in this post

I'm trying to set up a UITableView controller in storyboard, with a separate datasource, and I've hit a wall. The data source doesn't seem to respond to changes or push it's 'updates' to the table view. I've tried implementing the data source in the MainMenuTableViewController which worked fine.

This is my MainMenuTableViewController

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    sharedLightsManager.delegate = self
    sharedLightsManager.loadNetworkContext()

    dataSource = MainMenuTableViewDataSource(sharedLightsManager: sharedLightsManager)
    tableView.dataSource = dataSource
    tableView.delegate = dataSource

    title = "test"

}
//This method fires each time a change happens
func updateLights(){
    lights = sharedLightsManager.localNetworkContext.allLightsCollection.lights
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

MainMenuDataSource:

```
class MainMenuTableViewDataSource: NSObject, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate
{
    let reuseIdentifier = "tableViewCell"
    var sharedLightsManager: SharedLightsManager?
    var lights = []

    init(sharedLightsManager: SharedLightsManager)
    {
        self.sharedLightsManager = sharedLightsManager
    }
    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return lights.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell: UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("tableViewCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
        var lights = sharedLightsManager!.localNetworkContext.allLightsCollection.lights
        var light = LFXLight()
        if lights.count == 0 {
        println("Lights array still loading...")
        } else {
            light = lights[indexPath.row] as LFXLight
        }
        return cell
    }

}
```

and here is my outlets:

[image: Outlets]

I've just figured it out. A bit embarrassing. It was due to the `lights` array not having any objects in it, so obv. `lights.count` would return 0, therefore no rows...

Answer (score 0):

The data source will not push updates unless the UITableView is told to reloadData.  If you change the numberOfRows value, it will not update unless the tableView is notified through methods like insertRowAtIndexPath, reloadData, deleteRowAtIndexPath etc.

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that I do have a reloadData call that fires when updates happen. I've added that to the question.

Comment: Hmm, so you aren't seeing any rows at all?

Comment: I've just figured it out. A bit embarrassing. It was due to the `lights` array not having any objects in it, so obv. `lights.count` would return 0, therefore no rows... Sorry for wasting your time..!

Comment: No worries, congrats on figuring it out!  Hope your (i am guessing) HomeKit app works out well!

Comment: Thanks! It's an app for LIFX light bulbs :)